# How to get updated property values for BindableApplicationBarMenuItem?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, winrt-xaml

I am experiencing issues with BindableApplicationBar in windows phone.
I have added the BindableApplicationBarMenuItem from code behind with

- text
- IsEnabled property
- Visibility property

when I RaisePropertyChanged event for visibility attached property, it works fine.
But when I am trying fire RaisePropertyChanged event for IsEnabled attached property is doesn't work.

So how can I fire the RaisePropertyChanged event for IsEnabled attached property in case of BindableApplicationBarMenuItem.
or is there any other way to get the updated property value ?

Comment: Are you using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged ?

Comment: No...
In xaml 

<bar:BindableApplicationBarMenuItem Text="" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSomeProperty}"/>

and from code behind just

RaisePropertyChanged("IsSomeProperty")

Do i missing something ??